# Difference in speed between two MySQL servers

Tags: mysql, performance, master-slave

I have two MySQL servers. One is the master of other (actually the master is also a slave of another server). Both are running on similar remote servers (same amount of RAM). Everything is working fine except the slave is taking 2-3 times more time than the master server to run a same large query. Can someone think of a reason for this problem.

Comment: Have you checked the config file ?

Comment: Slave's config file has `query_cache_type = 1, query_cache_limit = 1M, query_cache_size = 32M, key_buffer_size = 24M`, and master's config file has `innodb_file_per_table=1, open_files_limit=21350, local-infile=0`. Everything else is almost the same.

Comment: Do you have `binlog/replicate-do/ignore-...` constraints on any of the 3 servers?  Is the Slave busy doing a lot of other reads, while the Master is not?

Comment: Please show us the "large query", together with `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` -- There could be useful clues in them.

Comment: @RickJames, Yes there are other parameters for setting up logs, has `replicate-do-db` in slave server.
I have asked a question here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31241447/optimize-mysql-queries-with-many-left-joins-and-group-by) to optimize the large query I was talking about. You can find the `<query>`, `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and `EXPLAIN <query>` there.

Answer (score 0):

If there are writes (coming from Master) to `a`, `b`, etc, then the `SELECT` will run slower on the Slave.  How much slower depends on far too many things to predict.

To 'prove' that, do (in the Slave) `STOP SLAVE SQL_THREAD;`, run the query; `START SLAVE SQL_THREAD;`.  That will turn off the writes for the SELECT.

But what about "fixing" it?

If the "writes" are INSERTs, can they be 'batched'?  That is, `INSERT` multiple rows in the same statement.  This may not 'solve' the problem, but it could mitigate it.

Comment: This worked for me : The tables in master server were using MyISAM engine where as those in slave were using Innodb engine. When I changed it MyISAM it was running as fast as the master. I don't know exact reason why it is so but, I have found many posts saying MyISAM is working faster than Innodb when running select queries Ex: [link](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/75091/why-are-simple-selects-on-innodb-100x-slower-than-on-myisam)

Comment: `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl;` (no `WHERE` clause) is about the only thing that reliably runs faster in MyISAM.  In your situation, it could be that the _table_ lock of MyISAM stalls the replicated writes so that the `SELECT` goes full speed.  But that _could_ mean that replication is often getting "behind".